# azure logic app how to change data in xml doc

Tags: xml, azure-logic-apps, edi, x12

Learning azure logic apps...I successfully decoded an X12 EDI message using 'transform XML'.  The problem is I need to change element data in in the resulting XML (AFTER the mapping).
As an example, XML element 'ISA06' will have data changed from 'DNE' to "ABC".

How can I parse an XML document, find an element and change its value?

Much appreciated for insight.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone is curious, in logic APPS I found a 'data operations' connector with operations 'compose', 'parse', and 'transform'.
In essence, the messages are transformed into JSON objects for manipulation.

I took the original message, composed it to json and parsed it...same for the decoded XML X12 820 message.  This created dynamic elements for each message allowing me to use 'transform' to recreate the decoded XML X12 820 message with updated data.

If someone has a more elegant solution, please give insight...
I would still like to do this through XML only.
...because parsing the messages required manually creating the JSON schemas for each message.

Comment: You could also make use of an Azure Integration Account. This allows you to build maps using XSLT. So at that point there is no need to convert to json. You can just use a Transform-action, give it the XML input of your EDI-message and apply an XSLT-transform on the XML. Output will again have the XML content type.

Comment: yes.  I used XSLT for a transform action.  QUESTION: Is it possible to use an XSLT mapping with 2 input schemas?  The problem I'm having is the first mapping works but I'd like to use the results in a new mapping...so I would need to input 2 schemas into the Transform?  I know I'm missing something obvious....appreciated

Comment: In BizTalk and with that maps is possible but I don't know if in the Transform component of the Logic Apps allows two instances, let me investigate

Comment: @Chappy if you need multiple input schemas that just means you need another transform with a single input

Answer (score 0):

The easiest is use XSLT maps as in BizTalk. You can develope a map in Visual Studio though Microsoft Azure Logic Apps Enterprise Integration Tools for Visual Studio 2015 2.0 and then you can add your maps into your Azure Enterprise Integration Account, see https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/logic-apps/logic-apps-enterprise-integration-maps.md

Comment: thanks.  I have taken advantage of XSLT.  The problem is after the mapping transformation, I need to modify the results with other data from another source.